# Reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 without using any image is Possible?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Is it possible to reinstall 14.04 without using any image?

I just upgraded into 14.04. There was a problem in my installation, Is it possible to reinstall ubuntu without any image.

Answer (score 1):

No, Ubuntu system not yet provide factory reset-like mechanism. Except you have done a system backup before using third party software. So, you can't, by default, restore your system to initial state.

Maybe later, you want to try backup software to avoid reinstalling : [BackInTime](http://backintime.le-web.org/). Install it by directly execute :

```
    sudo apt-get install backintime-gnome
```

Or if you want the latest, you can execute :

```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bit-team/stable
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install backintime-gnome
```

in your terminal.

Then backup your system as necessary.